# problems in mpi installation in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: mpi, ubuntu-10.04

I installed mpi on my Ubuntu 10.04 from terminal using the command

```
sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc
```

I required mpi for running some benchmarks which internally use mpi. when I am build the benchmarks using make command I get

```
make[1]: /usr/lib/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin/mpicxx: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/saikirangvr/gpgpu-sim/ispass2009-benchmarks/DG'
make[1]: /usr/lib/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin/mpicxx: Command not found
src/Mesh3d.c:1:17: error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
```

Is that my mpi not installed correctly or problem with other. how can I check whether mpi and all the required docs are installed perfectly......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two conflicting installations of MPI. You have one version of Open MPI and you installed another version of MPICH. You probably should uninstall both and try again with just one or the other.

UPDATE:

To summarize the extended comments below, the original poster had some issues with his environmental setup, specifically that the Makefile for the benchmarks was pointing to the wrong `mpixcc` and that the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` was not set correctly.

Comment: can you briefly describe how to uninstall them and install the correct version. Or please provide me the links for that....Thanks...

Comment: Unfortunately in Linux, unless you used a package manager, it is more difficult to go back an uninstall a different version. If you used a package manager, than it's as simple as 'apt-get uninstall openmpi' and 'apt-get uninstall mpich2`. Otherwise, you have to find out where they were installed and remove all of the executables and libraries by hand.

Comment: Another option is that the benchmark you're trying to run, just doesn't know where `mpicxx` is. You might need to check out the Makefile that it's using and ensure that the path is correct using `which mpicxx`.

Comment: when I type which mpicxx in terminal it returned, /usr/bin/mpicxx, and accordingly I edited the make file,then the error mpicxx command not found was overcame...., but the error mpi.h no such file or folder is still present..., what should i do

Comment: You need to correctly set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH for whatever directory mpi.h is in (if you don't know that, you can try `find / -name mpi.h`, though you'll get a lot of extra output that you'll have to wade through.

Comment: mpi.h is in usr/local/openmpi/include, now should I add /usr/local/openmpi/include to both of my path and Library_path in the ~/.bashrc file??

Comment: Oops. I said the wrong environment variable. For headers, it should be in the `C_INCLUDE_PATH`. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is to tell the linker where your libraries are. `PATH` is to tell the shell where you executables are. `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is to tell the compiler/linker where the headers are.

Comment: so now Export C_INCLUDE_PATH=C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/openmpi/include should be added to my ~/.bashrc file, and there is no need to modify the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in that file...

Comment: Correct. There's no need to modify those variables for this problem (you may have some other need to modify them for something else).

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work, the same mpi.h no such file or folder is still coming.......

Comment: Always remember to reload your bashrc after you've modified it. If your problem is solved, either mark one of our answers as correct or post your own answer and mark it as correct if you don't think these are adequate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linking/path problem, type into terminal `which mpicxx` and it should spit out that mpicxx is not found

you should have `mpicc` and `mpirun`

so all you need todo is configure your makefile parameters properly

Comment: when I type which mpicxx in terminal it returned, /usr/bin/mpicxx, and accordingly I edited the make file,then the error mpicxx command not found was overcame...., but the error mpi.h no such file or folder is still present..., what should i do

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing `libmpich-mpd1.0-dev` by using your package manager: